# Tkinter menu background is not changing

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a menu for a tkinter project
but I am facing some problems
the menu background is not changing

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
Menu1= tk.Menu(root, background="red")

filemenu = tk.Menu(Menu1, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New")
filemenu.add_command(label="Open")
filemenu.add_command(label="Save")
filemenu.add_command(label="Save as...")
filemenu.add_command(label="Close")
Menu1.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
root.config(menu=Menu1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think you can change the color of the menubar, though it might be tied to the color of the window itself. Have you tried changing the background color of the root window to see if that affects the color of the menu?

Comment: @BryanOakley I just tried a quick `self.config(background='orange')` and the menu bar stays gray (on Windows), alas

Comment: That's not overly surprising. Tkinter doesn't have control over the menubar - it's handed off to the OS to manage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background of the items in your File menu, you have to `config` that `Menu` instead of the root `Menu1`

```
filemenu.config(background='red')
```

If you want to color each menu item individually, you can set `background` for each `add_command`

```
filemenu.add_command(label="New", background='red')
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", background='orange')
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", background='yellow')
filemenu.add_command(label="Save as...", background='green')
filemenu.add_command(label="Close", background='blue')
```

Comment: thank you for your respond but I want to change the whole menu

Comment: If you're talking about changing the background of the root menu (the part that says `File`), I'm not sure there's a way to do that.